# Help understanding the geometric interpretation of the area of 2 multivectors

Tags: geometry, clifford-algebras

Given two vectors:

$$
v_1=\sigma_x x_1+\sigma_y y_1\\
v_2=\sigma_x x_2 +\sigma_y y_2
$$

The area can be computed as the wedge product

$$
\begin{align}
A&=v_1\wedge v_2 \\
&=(\sigma_x x_1 + \sigma_y y_1)\wedge(\sigma_x x_2+\sigma_y y_2)\\
&=(x_1y_2-x_2y_2)\sigma_x\wedge \sigma_y
\end{align}
$$

My question is can we extend this concept to multivectors, and if so, what is the geometric meaning of the "multi-area"?

$$
u_1=a_1+\sigma_x x_1+\sigma_y y_1\\
u_2=a_2+\sigma_x x_2 +\sigma_y y_2
$$

$$
\begin{align}
A_M&=(a_1+\sigma_x x_1+\sigma_y y_1)\wedge (a_2+\sigma_x x_2 +\sigma_y y_2)\\
&=a_1 a_2 + (a_2 x_1 + a_1 x_2) \sigma_x + (a_2 y_1 + a_1 y_2) \sigma_y + (a_2 b_1 + a_1 b_2 - x_2 y_1 + x_1 y_2) \sigma_x \wedge \sigma_y
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Why you think it relates to area? See here the interpretation which is actually for physics, for example the moment exerted by a force...

Comment: @Moti - Where is "here"?

Comment: @Mito I would also love a link for 'here'